# ArrayList and Nodes

Tags: java, class, arraylist, parameters, linked-list

I trying to rewrite a constructor for `AssassinManager` (see below). **This method is a constructor that takes in an ArrayList as a parameter. The ArrayList should add names into the object in the exact order as they appear. Each new node should be added to the end of the linked list.** I'm not sure how to achieve this, given new properties to play with.

First version:

```
private static class AssassinNode {
    private String player; 
    private String killer; 
    private AssassinNode next;
    private AssassinNode(String name) {
        this.player = name; 
        this.killer = null; 
        this.next = null;
    } 
}

private AssassinNode killring;  // the head of the kill ring linked list - first link
private AssassinNode graveyard; // the head of the graveyard linked list - second link 

public AssassinManager(ArrayList<String> players) { 
    if (players == null || players.isEmpty()) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
    killring = new AssassinNode(players.get(0)); // create first node - for the killring
    AssassinNode node = killring; 
    for (int i = 1; i < players.size(); i++) { // Add a new node at the end of each killing 
        node.next = new AssassinNode(players.get(i));
        node = node.next;
    }
}
```

The new version:

```
private KillList killring; 
private AssassinNodeData graveyard;

public AssassinManager(ArrayList<String> players) {
    if (players == null || players.isEmpty()) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
    killring = new KillList(players.get(0));
    KillList node = killring; 
    node.addAll(players); 
}
```

`KillList extends LinkedList<AssassinNodeData>` Now I'm trying to achieve the same thing without using `next`.

Relationship between classes: KillList (subclass) and AssassinNodeData (superclass)

Any suggestions or solutions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to write an insert method, but generally the only way to add to a linked list is to use the next attribute to iterate over the list

Comment: node.addAll(players), try like this

Comment: Hello @cricket_007 :) So you mean like the only way is to have it how I have it in the first version? I'm not familiar with what you're alluding to - write an insert method?

Comment: @Hemakumar Thanks for the suggestion - let me see what it does!

Comment: @Hemakumar unfortunately - that did not work!

Comment: "That did not work" doesn't tell us what happened vs what you wanted to happen. It would be much easier to help you if you would provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does `new KillList(players.get(0))` really return a `List`? Are you able to change the constructor for `AssassinNode`?

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet ! Sorry I wasn't more precise. When I did what Hemakumar suggested, I got an error and the compiler suggested me to create an addAll method to my `KillList` method. Which I don't think is what supposed to happen.

Comment: "I got an error" is again far from precise. (The compiler gives you an error message - you should include that when reporting what went wrong.) Again, if you were to provide a [mcve] it would be very much easier to help you.

Comment: @SubOptimal the first version belongs a class that contains a method calls AssassinNode. `killring = new AssassinNode(players.get(0))` is suppose to create the head node.

Comment: (It doesn't help that `AssassinNode` appears to form its own linked list *and* you've got a `LinkedList<AssassinNodeData>`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Following when I said "I got an error" I followed with what the error suggested. Please read into it before judgement. Would you like to see what I have for `AssassinNode`? I just updated the code for further clarification to my question.

Comment: "What the error suggested" isn't the same as copying and pasting the error message verbatim. What I would like is a [mcve]. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/run the code to see the problem, with no code present that's *not* related to the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114585/discussion-between-ani-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: If `KillList extends LinkedList<AssassinNodeData>` ... then `KillList` have method `addAll(collection)` from Its parent `LinkedList<AssassinNodeData>`

Comment: @Hemakumar: Yes, but the type of `players` is `ArrayList<string>`, not `ArrayList<AssassinNodeData>`.

Comment: @Hemakumar Since KillList extends LinkedList<AssassinNodeData> I assume KillList should be able to implement LinkList methods such as addAll()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to change the `AssassinNode` you might do it like this.

```
public class AssassinNode {

    private final String player;
    private AssassinNode parent;
    private AssassinNode child = null;

    AssassinNode(String player, AssassinNode parent) {
        this.player = player;
        this.parent = parent;
        addToParent(parent);
    }

    void setChild(AssassinNode child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    private void addToParent(AssassinNode parent) {
        parent.setChild(this);
    }
    // other getters and code
}
```

.

```
public class AssassinManager {

    LinkedList<AssassinNode> killring = new LinkedList<>();

    public AssassinManager(List<String> players) {
        if (players == null || players.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        AssassinNode assassin = null;
        for (String player : players) {
            assassin = new AssassinNode(player, assassin);
            killring.add(assassin);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> players = Arrays.asList("eizo", "shay", "arno", "arbaaz");
        AssassinManager manager = new AssassinManager(players);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I tried your solution and implemented my own ways - however `killring.add(assassin)` show an error that says "no suitable method found for add(AssassinNode)" and the alternative is to create an `add(AssassinNode)` method in the AssassinNode.

Comment: @Ani You said `KillList extends LinkedList<AssassinNodeData>` so it should have an `add`. As you didn't told what's the difference between `AssassinNodeData` and `AssassinNode` I assumed they meant the same.

Comment: No, they are different. Hence their names.  Can you elaborate on the add(). Like create an add method in the KillList class?

Comment: @Ani I believe you should better describe your class structure and what you want to achieve. If `KillList extends LinkedList` following cant be true at the same time `KillList (subclass) and AssassinNodeData (superclass)`. Or it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. However, your solution hints at some very helpful things so I will accept it and see where I can go from there! Thank you so much for your help ^^